# SQL stored procedure string query

Tags: sql

How will I include a table in my string query?

ERROR:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@LocationIds".

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @YEAR AS NVARCHAR(4)
SET @YEAR = '2023'

DECLARE @LocationIds AS TABLE(Id int)

INSERT INTO @LocationIds
VALUES (1), (13)

SET @query = N'SELECT LocationId, ['+@YEAR+'] FROM 
             (
                SELECT LocationId, IntegralApparentDelta, Year
                FROM vvMonitorWithDelta l 
                WHERE l.LocationId IN (SELECT Id FROM  '+ @LocationIds +')  
            ) x
            pivot (
            (
                sum(IntegralApparentDelta)
                for Year in (['+ @YEAR +'])
            ) p'

PRINT @query
EXECUTE (@query)


LocationId  2023
--------------------
1         18.0920
13        200708.0560
```

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: The `@LocationIds` variable is a table, but you're trying to use it as a string, to concatenate it as part of query. That will not work. Nor can you reference it direct (`Execute()` creates a different execution context where the variable is not available.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you explain what you are trying to achieve then we may be able to help with a different method.